# How to use the MySQL CONVERT_TZ function in a JPQL or HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, timezone, timestamp, hql

I currently have table in a `MySQL` database which has a `startDate` and `endDate` which are both `timestamps`. This is linked to the code using hibernate.

I can return these by using the following HQL

```
SELECT startDate, endDate FROM Reservation where id = :id
```

What I am trying to do is return these dates based on a given timezone. I know MySQL has a function `CONVERT_TZ` which can return the dates based on a given timezone, I'm wondering if HQL has a similar function?

I know HQL has a `TIMESTAMP_WITH_ZONE` function but this uses a local timezone when I need to specify the timezone, can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Since Hibernate ORM 5.2.18

Since 5.2.18, you can register SQL functions via the [`MetadataBuilderContributor`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/):

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor 
        implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
         
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "convert_tz", 
            new StandardSQLFunction( "convert_tz", StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP )
        );
    }
}
```

Ans simply provide the `MetadataBuilderContributor` via the `hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor` configuration property:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor" 
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"
</property>
```

### Prior to Hibernate ORM 5.2.18

Or, if you bootstrap with the Hibernate native mechanism, you can register the function when constructing the `MetadataBuilder` as explained in the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native-metadata).

A very common, yet naive way to register a SQL function, is override the MySQL Dialect and register the new function like this:

```
class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public CustomMySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction( "convert_tz", new StandardSQLFunction( "convert_tz", StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP ) );
    }

}
```

The configure Hibernate to use the new dialect:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor" 
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.CustomMySQLDialect"
</property>
```