# Make mysql convert_tz function work on a H2 database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm writing a test under an H2 in memory DB that using MySql dialect(`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`), Since we run that one in production.

On one the repositories we have a custom query with the block:

`DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'GMT', (:timezoneOffset)))`

How ever, H2 throws the following error:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "convert_tz" not found;`

I tried the solutions suggested in this post:
[How to use the MySQL CONVERT_TZ function in a JPQL or HQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725820/how-to-use-the-mysql-convert-tz-function-in-a-jpql-or-hql-query/31741171)

Also tried with a `SQLFunctionTemplate` like in this examples: https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder/applySqlFunction

But I keep getting the exact same error. And don't see any other workaround to make it work. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If h2 does not support this function, then I do not think there is anything you can do!

Comment: H2 has a timestamp with time zone data type (https://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#timestamp_with_time_zone). I think you can use its cast function to convert from one to another time zone.